# Undefined index error in PHP fixed but still data is not submitted to the database

Tags: php, forms

I have been doing a php tutorial on forms. First I got the error undefined index.
After watching some videos I fixed it applying isset function.But still data is not submitted to the database. Before this one I successfully did another simple example with two inputs. I don't understand why it happened only for this example. And I want to know how to fix this. Except this I also want to know about the function header here. I have no idea why it is used here. I'm new to php.Thanks!

Here are my codes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<h1>Student Registration</h1>
<form action="insert1.php" method="post">
<label>ID</label>
<input type="text" name="id"/>
</br>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name"/>
</br>
<label>Sex</label>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="f"/>Female
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="m"/>Male</br>
<label>Class</label>
<input type="text" name="class"/>
</br>
<button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$id=$_POST['id'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$sex=$_POST['sex'];
$id=$_POST['class'];

$hostname='localhost';
$dbuser='root';
$dbpass='123';
$dbname='school';

$conn=mysqli_connect($hostname,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
$sql="insert into student values('".$id."','".$name."','".$sex."','".$class."')";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
mysqli_close();
//header('location:form4.html');
}
?>
```

Code for select query

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Sex</th>
<th>Class</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$hostname="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="123";
$dbname="sem3";
$conn=mysqli_connect($hostname,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
$sql="select * from student";
$results=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    $g=$row['sex'];
    if($g="m")
        echo "<td>Male</td>";
    else
        echo "<td>Female</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['class']."</td>";
    echo "<tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<a href="form4.html">Add Customer</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please give the mysql table structure..

Comment: I'd recommend using `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {` over checking if a button is submitted. You have no need for the submit button to be past as a value in the form, and you don't want to bind your front end to the back end for that if you don't have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to add a `name` to your `button`:

`<button type="submit" name="submit">OK</button>`

Or else this will not not pass:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

And in this example, `$class` does not exists int his line:

`$sql="insert into student values('".$id."','".$name."','".$sex."','".$class."')";`

You could update `$id=$_POST['class'];` to `$class=$_POST['class'];`

Comment: It helped. I could submit data applying those changes. And then I tried to execute a select query and got a error called,
( ! ) Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\PHP\form6.php on line 22
Can you please help me fix this? And also I did some change in above code due to the error mysqli_close().I used the parameter $conn and it worked.Am I right or wrong? I'll include the code for select query in the post.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

write this `<button type="submit" name="submit">OK</button>` instead of `<button type="submit">OK</button>`

you should have to mention the tag name then it will be set into post method

Answer (score 0):

You've written the wrong query for inserting the data. Here's the right format for [insert query](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp). Also, add a name to your button because without it $_POST['submit'] won't work.

```html
<button type="submit" name="submit">OK</button>
```

In PHP, 'header' is used for two major purposes.The first is a header that starts with the string "HTTP/" (case is not significant), which will be used to figure out the HTTP status code to send. The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser. You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).